# (407) Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy

I know that this error is very common, but I tried to apply the solutions to this problem and could not solve it.

Thats my code:

```
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://www3prz.bancobonsucesso.com.br/Servicos/app.svc"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("bancobonsucesso.com.br"));
        var binding = new WSHttpBinding();

        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = true;
        binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;

        var customBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);

        SymmetricSecurityBindingElement security = customBinding.Elements.Find<SymmetricSecurityBindingElement>();
        security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        security.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;

        SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters secureTokenParams = (SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters)security.ProtectionTokenParameters;
        SecurityBindingElement bootstrap = secureTokenParams.BootstrapSecurityBindingElement;
        bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;

        ws = new ServicoClient(customBinding, endpoint);
        ws.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
        ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test";

        var return = ws.EmitirBoleto("test");
```

Comment: You really need to do more than just post a dump of a whole bunch of code and an error message.  Talk to us.  You say you've tried a bunch of things, well, what have you tried?  What have you looked at that wasn't helpful?  What are you actually trying to do that isn't working?  What line is the error actually occurring on?  Does it always happen, or just sometimes?  If sometimes, what do you know about when it happens?

Comment: The error occurs on the line "ws.EmitirBoleto("test")".

Everywhere you looked, the tip was to use the "binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true", but the error remains the same with or without this option.

If I run on a machine that has no proxy, works perfectly, but when I set up a proxy in internet explorer, starts giving this error.

I hope I have been clearer.

Comment: You should edit all of that information into the actual question, rather than leaving it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN the WCF Binding use useDefaultWebProxy:

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="bindingName"  useDefaultWebProxy="true">

WebProxy wproxy = new WebProxy("new proxy",true);
wproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = wproxy;
```

Comment: The line "ws = new ServicoClient (customBinding, endpoint)" refers to a class System.ServiceModel.ClientBase. I cannot find object/property WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy

Comment: What I did not know was WebRequest was a static class

Answer (score 0):

This error may arise problem with proxy settings.
Please check Proxy setting with your web browser. Just changed connection settings  Option -> settings -> connection settings to **Auto detect proxy settings**

Good luck ...